# How do you use ruby gems after they have been installed on OS X

Tags: ruby, json, rubygems

I am able to install the json library using ruby gems. In case it's relevant, I'm using the latest OS X.

```
usr$ sudo gem install json
Password:
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed json-1.6.5
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for json-1.6.5...
Installing RDoc documentation for json-1.6.5...
```

However, attempting to `require 'json'` it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

```
touakas-MacBook-Pro:tmp jacob$ ruby x.rb
x.rb:3:in `require': no such file to load -- json (LoadError)
    from x.rb:2
```

The x.rb is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'json'

x = { "a"=>"b" }
print x.to_json
```

Comment: Can you give this a shot: `ruby -rubygems x.rb`

Comment: JSON is part of Ruby 1.9.x std-lib http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON/Ext/Generator/GeneratorMethods/Hash.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to load RubyGems first:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'json'
```

**Edit:**

According to the comment below, you'd better use `ruby -rubygems x.rb` rather than `require rubygems` directly (suppose that you're writing a module for resue).

**Credit to:** @injekt and @Ingenu

Comment: Please avoid using `require 'rubygems'` and do as @Ingenu said in their comment: `ruby -rubygems x.rb` -- see http://www.rubyinside.com/why-using-require-rubygems-is-wrong-1478.html for more information